# BaseSpider and CrawlSpider together

Tags: python, scrapy

I would like to know if there is a way of using both the Base spider as well as the Crawl spider within the same spider in scrapy!

Suppose i wanted to crawl only one `url` mentioned in the `start_url` and use crawl spider for another page mentioned within the same `start_url`, how would i use them within the same program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do that is to use `CrawlSpider` with the rules your need, and override the `start_requests` method to generate:

- requests to be parsed using `CrawlSpider` built-in magic, so you need to set the callback for these to `self.parse`
- requests for be parsed by another callback

Example:

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    ...
    start_urls_crawlspider = (url1, url2,)
    start_urls_basespider = (url3,)

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls_crawlspider :
            yield Request(url, callback=self.parse) # "parse" is the default anyway

        for url in self.start_urls_basespider:
            yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_base)

    def parse_base(self, response):
        ...
```