# Python Scrapy: passing properties into parser

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm new to Scrapy and web-scraping in general so this might be a stupid question but it wouldn't be the first time so here goes.

I have a simple Scrapy spider, based on the tutorial example, that processes various URLs (in start_urls).  I would like to categorise the URLs e.g. URLs A, B, and C are Category 1, while URLS D and E are Category 2, then be able to store the category on the resulting Items when the parser processes the response for each URL.

I guess I could have a separate spider for each category, then just hold the category as an attribute on the class so the parser can pick it up from there.  But I was kind of hoping I could have just one spider for all the URLs, but tell the parser which category to use for a given URL.

Right now, I'm setting up the URLs in start_urls via my spider's **init**() method. How do I pass the category for a given URL from my **init** method to the parser so that I can record the category on the Items generated from the responses for that URL?

Comment: I think you can achieve that by overriding the `start_requests()` method, adding a "category" key and value in the Requests's `meta` dict. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21556644/basespider-and-crawlspider-together for something not far off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As paul t. suggested:

```py
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):

    def start_requests(self):
        ...
        yield Request(url1, meta={'category': 'cat1'}, callback=self.parse)
        yield Request(url2, meta={'category': 'cat2'}, callback=self.parse)
        ...

    def parse(self, response):
        category = response.meta['category']
        ...
```

You use `start_requests` to have control over the first URLs you're visiting, attaching metadata to each URL, and you can access that metadata through `response.meta` afterwards.

Same thing if you need to pass data from a `parse` function to a `parse_item`, for instance.